# How to send multiple DateTime from form to controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, forms, datetime

I am making a form generated from a Model class with RazorEngine. There is a list or period.

Model:

```
public IDictionary<string,DateofTrainingSession> TrainingMultiDatePeriod { get; set; }


public class DateofTrainingSession {
    public DateTime StartingDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndingDate { get; set; }
}
```

In the form it can be added multiple TrainingMultiDatePeriod, with Javacript. However, I have a problem with date format. C# doesn't understand the Js date object.

In a nutshell:
1/ How to send multiple period?
2/ How to handle Date Object from JS to C#?

Thanks,

Stéphane.

EDIT (CODE ADDED after Comment):
Jquery:

```
$('#buttonaddperiod').on('click', function () {
            //Add new period
            var enddate = new Date(getDate($('#TrEndDate').val()));
            var startingdate = new Date(getDate($('#TrStartDate').val()));

            if ((enddate.getTime() >= startingdate.getTime()) && $('#TrEndDate').val()!="" &&$('#TrEndDate').val()!="") {
                var index = new Date().getTime();
                var datedif = parseInt(new Number(enddate.getTime() / 86400000 - startingdate.getTime() / 86400000).toFixed(0)) + 1;

                $("#groupePeriode ul").append('<li><input type="datetime" hidden name="TrainingMultiDatePeriod[' + index + '].StartingDate" value="' +
                    startingdate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + startingdate.toLocaleTimeString() + '"><input type="datetime" hidden name="TrainingMultiDatePeriod[' + index + '].EndingDate" value="' +
                    enddate.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + enddate.toLocaleTimeString() + '"><input hidden name="TrainingMultiDatePeriod[' + index + '].Id" value="-1"> <input value="' + startingdate.toLocaleDateString()
                + ' au ' + enddate.toLocaleDateString() + '" readonly class="liste verylong"/></li>');

                $("#groupeNbDay ul").append('<li><input value="' + datedif
                 + '" readonly class="liste short"/><a href="#">supprimer</a></li>');
```

HTML/Razor:

```
<td>
                    <div id="groupeNbDay" class="classique certifiante diplomante">
                        <ul>
                            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.NbDaysList.ToList().Count; i++)
                            {
                                var period = Model.TrainingMultiDatePeriod.ElementAt(i);
                                <li>
                                    <input value="@(Model.NbDaysList.ToList()[i])" readonly class="liste short">
                                    <a href="#">supprimer</a>

                                </li>
                            }

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Comment: Can you show us your view code, and the way you are submitting your form?

Comment: Done. Is that code enough?

Comment: I don't see how you submit your form. Is it a simple form that will be submitted to the same URL? Or an Ajax call?